# Haskell: what is the fastest way to pipe data from handle to a handle?

Tags: linux, sockets, haskell, handle

How can I define

```
pipe :: Handle -> Handle -> IO ()
```

in the most efficient way in Haskell (platform 2011-04 or ghc 7.4)?

---

**Update 1**: [How to write a minimal-overhead proxy to localhost:3389 in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459043/how-to-write-a-simple-minimal-overhad-proxy-to-localhost-3389-in-haskell)

---

**Update 2**: [Using GNU/Linux system call `splice` for zero-copy Socket to Socket data transfers in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080670/using-gnu-linux-system-call-splice-for-zero-copy-socket-to-socket-data-transfe)

Uses the GNU/Linux system call `splice` for zero-copy data piping between two network sockets, also makes room for a portable socket-to-socket `splice` substitute written in Haskell, which uses (`mallocBytes`, `hGetBufSome` and `hPutBuf`) a one-time allocated user space buffer throughout the data transfer loop avoiding tiny allocations that lead to pressure on the garbage collector with repeated calls to `recv`, `sendAll` from the `bytestring` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll find any non-FFI solution that significantly beats either:

```
almostForever $ Data.ByteString.hGetSome h1 nr >>= Data.ByteString.hPutStr h2
```

Or perhaps you'd gain a little using lazy byte strings:

```
Data.ByteString.Lazy.hGetContents  h1 >>= Data.ByteString.Lazy.hPut h2
```

If you have time then run a benchmark of these.  If you don't have time, then just do one and don't worry so much about performance unless it's actually an issue.

Comment: "If you don't have time, then just do one and don't worry so much about performance unless it's actually an issue." ^_^ I guess both will be significantly faster than what I could come up with on my own. It is the first time I see someone explicitly think of someone's time constraints!

Comment: where does almostForever live? Hoogle claims not to be able to find it.

Comment: @benw when Hoogle can't find it, try [Hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html). However, in this case, Hayoo can't find `almostForever` either. >,<

Comment: +1 I personally find the lazy `hGetContents` to be a very elegant and intuitive solution.

Comment: @benw `almostForever` was just my made-up function ment to imply the looping construct was up to the asker, would probably last more than one loop and not quite forever.  Like computing `ackerman 10 10`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are dealing with sockets, because of your tags.

If this is the case, use the [`sendfile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sendfile) package to perform the operation with [`sendFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/sendfile/0.7.4/doc/html/Network-Socket-SendFile-Handle.html#v%3asendfile). Note that you have to use the Haskell networking library and real sockets; it doesn't work with handles.

If you are dealing with abstract handles, you need to do what @thomas-m-dubuisson suggested and copy the handles explicitly, because you need some kind of buffering to make the operation efficient. You shouldn't use lazy byte strings, however, because `hGetSome` will not read enough to make lazy byte strings more efficient.

```
almostForever $ Data.ByteString.hGetSome h1 nr >>= Data.ByteString.hPutStr h2
```